# green header file

Tags: 12.04, command-line, colors

In terminal, when I type `ls`, I see some header files (like foo.h) in green. As far as I know, green corresponds to executable files. So why some of the those header files are in green?

Comment: Are they on a FAT/NTFS partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is green because its permissions say it is executable.  You can see the permissions with `ls -l`.  Because FAT/NTFS do not store permissions all files on volumes using these Windows formats will show as executable.  If the file is not on a Windows volume, then you can change the permissions with the `chmod` command.  `chmod a-x foo.h` will remove all 3 execute bits ( owner, group, other ) from the file and stop it showing as green.

Answer (score 0):

That is a function of the terminal program you use. For example in my terminal, it does not display in green. But if I mark a file like test.h to executable, it will. Different terminal programs display that information based on what that author decided.